# picasso illegal argument exception

Tags: android

i am working on an application where i have to load images from url using picasso's library.
when i run my app, it crashes and i don't know whats the problem.
can anyone help me please ?

this is my main activity code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivityLazy extends ActionBarActivity
{
    String[] urls;
    GridView gridview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_lazy);

        urls = new String[] { "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Sad-icon.png", 
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Happy-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Crying-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Cool-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-In-love-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Lol-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Surprised-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Tongue-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Wink-icon.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image0.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image1.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image2.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image3.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image4.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image5.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image6.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image7.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image8.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image9.png",
                              "http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/LazyListView_images/image10.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Sad-icon.png", 
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Happy-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Crying-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Cool-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-In-love-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Lol-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Surprised-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Tongue-icon.png",
                              "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/512/Emoticons-Wink-icon.png"
                            };

        GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(MainActivityLazy.this, urls);
        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

this is my gridviewadapter code :

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private String[] mUrls;
    private Context mContext;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, String[] urls) {
        //super(context, flag);
        mContext = context;
        mUrls = urls;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row, null);
        }

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mUrls[position]).into(imageView);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src)
    {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

this is my logcat errors :

```
07-30 09:54:58.995: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(23926): Parent view is not a TextView
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926): Process: com.example.lazyload, PID: 23926
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:479)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:462)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at com.example.lazyload.GridViewAdapter.getView(GridViewAdapter.java:45)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2733)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1049)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:382)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6388)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the key lines of your log cat.

```
07-30 09:54:58.995: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(23926): Parent view is not a TextView

07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

07-30 09:54:59.070: E/AndroidRuntime(23926):    at com.example.lazyload.GridViewAdapter.getView(GridViewAdapter.java:45)
```

This line is the cause of the exception:
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(mUrls[position]).into(imageView);

At row 45 in `GridViewAdapter.getView()` you got a IllegalArgumentException. Use Log.d to check what you are sending in to the picasso. With regard to the first error message i would guess that `R.id.image` is a `TextView` and not an `ImageView`.

Comment: i figured out what was the problem and i posted it

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same answer that i posted, but 3 minutes lates? I stated that R.id.image was not an imageView. I'm sad to hear that you don't think I'm worth an accept(mark as solved) for posting the same answer.

Comment: thanks a lot and sorry ! when i solved the problem i did not read the answer beacause i had already solved it ! sorry again

Comment: Thanks! Good luck in the feature :)